# Cannot load Gnome-terminal

Tags: 16.04, python, gnome-terminal

This is definitely a user profile issue rather than an issue with the PC as other people do not have this problem using the same PC, and the user has the same problem on every PC that he logs into.

No error message appears when the terminal is launched the icon pops up briefly and then it disappears, Xterm launches okay. I have tried to rename several folders in ~ including .config .local .gconf but nothing seems to help :(

I have read that this can be something to do with python however he has no installs of python in his home directory. 
I have looked at the users xsession-errors and it referenced a crash log which also mentions python so I wondered if somehow this could be part of the issue:

```
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.5
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

If anybody else has experienced a problem similar to this and has any suggestions I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What is the value of `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to resolve this!

The user had a .py file in their home directory when he was opening ipython it was compiling the file (I'm not very familiar with python/ipython myself). Removing the .pyc and .py file resolved the issue! They can now open a gnome-terminal again.